# Delete Tableview's Row from Detailview

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have used storyboard in my application in my detail view for `UITableView` i passed tableview to detail view to be able to delete this row depend on something action but give me below error

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', 
reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  
The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (4) must be equal to the  
number of rows contained in that section before the update (4),
plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) 
and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you delete the last row in your table, the UITableView code expects there to be 0 rows remaining. It calls your `UITableViewDataSource` methods to determine how many are left. Since you have a "No data" cell, it returns 1, not 0. So when you delete the last row in your table, try calling `-insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` to insert your "No data" row.

**What you need to do is :**

```
// tell the table view you're going to make an update
[tableView beginUpdates];
// update the data object that is supplying data for this table
// ( the object used by tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: )
[dataArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
// tell the table view to delete the row
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPath 
           withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
// tell the table view that you're done
[tableView endUpdates];
```

( According to this [link](http://timroadley.com/2012/02/14/core-data-basics-part-3-editing-and-deleting/) , you should avoid `NSInternalInconsistencyException`. )

Comment: Get me error No visible @interface for UITableView declares the selector 'beginUdate'

Comment: I added one link in my answer, you can check that.

Comment: It should be `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates`.

Answer (score 0):

When you add or delete a row you must update your datasource to keep consistency. It seems that your datasource is not updated after deleting the row. To help you it will be useful your datasource methods and the code you use to delete the row.

Answer (score 0):

Your log means that **4-1 = 3, not 4**.

You have to take into consideration your deleted rows when returning their count in

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

You should have a variable or array containing your number of rows, e.g.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.cellsCount;
}

// somewhere else

[tableView beginUpdates];
self.cellsCount--; // here is an important line of code
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPath withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: No need for self.cellsCount after you remove this object from array

Comment: Yeah, you didn't say you have an array.