# How can I delete selected row from UITableView?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, ios4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [change Table to Edit mode and delete Rows inside a normal ViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14148229/change-table-to-edit-mode-and-delete-rows-inside-a-normal-viewcontroller)

I want to delete selected row from tableView. I want to provide the functionality to the user to delete the row when he slips or flicks his finger on the row. I know the editing style which provides a circular red button with -ve sign on it.

I have tried this code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{


[tableView beginUpdates];    
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    // Do whatever data deletion you need to do...
    // Delete the row from the data source
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];      
}       
[tableView endUpdates];
[tableView reloadData];
}
```

I get the delete button but when I click it SIGABRT Error is there.

Comment: You can check my answer Here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14030944/how-can-i-delete-tableview-row-from-detail-view/14031052#14031052

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try like below lines:

```
[bookmarks removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

bookmarks is my array name that I load on table view cell you should give your array name in place of this.

Comment: its work but when i add another data all deleted data are show again ?

Comment: in end again select that array again means to say reload your data of array using select that array again in end...

Comment: As in my case I am again give array to NSUserDefault for relaoad in end like: [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:bookmarks forKey:@"Bookmarks"];

Comment: @Vishal i give this answer but late and wrong about that , but you solve it very well and easily.. keep it up dude:)

Comment: suppose i have cell0 ,cell1 , cell2
I delete cell1 , then in tableview i have shown cell0 and cell1 only
Now again if i delete cell1 then it kills ? explain

Comment: @iphonemaclover: After delete row and data from Array you have to reload your data Array and then check...

Answer (score 3):

After removing the table row delete the corresponding index dataSource from your dataSource to table.and then reload table again.

```
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
 [dataArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  [tableView reloadData];
```

Answer (score 3):

just replace the Code

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle==UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    { 
        [dataArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }


    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 [tableArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

Answer (score 0):

Must Try This....

```
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:YES];
```