# Is it possible to delete a row in a UITableView by selection?

Tags: ios, uitableview, row

I have an app that allows a user to make a selection from a `UITableView`. I'm somewhat familiar with adding the ability to edit and delete them, but I was wondering if it is possible to delete the row based purely on selecting it? If so, does anyone know how the code to do so would look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In method didSelectedRowAtIndexPath delete element from datasource and than cell from tableView, there is a code for your problem [delete row from tableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14191057/how-can-i-delete-selected-row-from-uitableview).

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy! I'll mark this as the right answer once Stack allows me to in 8 minutes.