# UITableView rows insertion, deletion, updation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am creating an ios app in which i want to add each new row at the top in the `UITableView` but the already existing row should not be deleted.

For example i have a cell in row 1 when i click on it it will display the image the same image should be displayed even when we insert a new cell in row 1 and the old one moved to row 2.

I have searched it in stackoverflow but i could not understand what they have explained. So can anyone provide the tutorial or the sample application to insert, delete and update the row in `UITableView` in ios.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you are adding new cell then Insert your cell data on **ZERO** index like this

```
NSMutableArray *dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Hello",@"How Are You", nil]; 

// It's your data array that you have already allocation in viewDidLoad or some where else.. 


[dataArray insertObject:@"Joy" atIndex:0];  // Try this line on add there your are adding new cell data

[tableView beginUpdates];
NSIndexPath *indexpath = [NSIndexPath indexPathforRow:0 inSection:0];
NSArray *indextoadd = [NSArray arrayWithObject:indexpath1];
[tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indextoadd withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

Using this array will auto sort and "Joy" name will inserted on ZERO index and array auto shifted

after this Reload your tableview

```
[tableviewObj reloadData];
```

try this hope you will got success.  For fully table Example [UITableView example in iOS](http://www.makemegeek.com/uitableview-example-ios/)

- For delete row  Check it.. [How can I delete selected row from UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14191057/how-can-i-delete-selected-row-from-uitableview)
- For Update row check it .. [refresh a single UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448321/is-it-possible-to-refresh-a-single-uitableviewcell-in-a-uitableview)

  In update before reload you table replace date in your array

  [dataArray replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:newObject];

Comment: what about delete and update

Comment: I have updated my answer check it..

Comment: but by using your code for insertion it is adding row in bottom of the table not as first row

Comment: But I have tested this, It's adding on zero index of array then How can It's show on last...

Comment: I agree. Its adding on zero index of array. Can u provide me the cellforrowatindexpath code

Comment: See at here ... Full code of all function .. http://pastebin.com/tCrzSLrT

Answer (score 2):

```
- (void)insertRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation;
- (void)deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation;
- (void)reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation;
```

These three methods you can use for delete,insert and update table row.
Here Apple code for insertRowAtIndexPaths [click here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/EADemo/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010079)